# how to replace a specific character that comes after a specific string and n other characters with sed?

Tags: linux, sed

i tried looking into old postS but but didnt get my answer thanks in advance!
i have files which indisei have lines with same pattern
i would like to replace one of the following [mau] with "A" after a specific string for example:
n=22 string="abnt7777/knowthis" char to change "m"

abnt7777/knowthisDONTKNOWWICHCAHRACTERSmRESTOFSTRING

what i know is the string that comes first "abnt7777/knowthis"
aswell i know how many charcaters between "abnt7777/knowthis" and a which is 22
after the change would be:

abnt7777/knowthisDONTKNOWWICHCAHRACTERSARESTOFSTRING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
echo "abnt7777/knowthisDONTKNOWWICHCAHRACTERSmRESTOFSTRING" | sed 's#\(abnt7777/knowthis.\{22\}\)m#\1A#'
```

prints

```
abnt7777/knowthisDONTKNOWWICHCAHRACTERSARESTOFSTRING
```

The `sed` command searches for `abnt7777/knowthis` followed by 22 characters followed by `m`. All characters except the `m` are enclosed in `\(` and `\)` to capture it as group 1. The matching string is replaced by group 1 (`\1`) followed by `A`. All other parts of the line will remain unchanged.

If you want to replace the strings in the contents of a file, use something like

```bsh
sed 's#\(abnt7777/knowthis.\{22\}\)m#\1A#' inputfile > outputfile
```

Note: If your real input pattern is something else than `abnt7777/knowthis` you have to check if it contains characters that are special for regular expressions in `sed`.

Comment: thank u Bodo! works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

With variable expansion, if I understand you correctly:

```
foo="abnt7777/knowthisDONTKNOWWICHCAHRACTERSmRESTOFSTRING"
echo ${foo:0:39}A${foo:40}
```

Output:

```
abnt7777/knowthisDONTKNOWWICHCAHRACTERSARESTOFSTRING
                                      #^ 39 position (17 abnt7777/knowthis + 22)
```